# how to specify variables in JSON object in integration test in grails

Tags: json, grails, integration-testing

I'm writing an integration test for an API in grails. This API under test takes a JSON request and returns a JSON response only. Lets say the request JSON is :
{ "param1":value1,"param2":value2}

In this request, value1 and value2 depends on some other variables. So how can i put them in request JSON

A code snippet :

```
void testMethod(){

def controller = new DummyController()
Long param1Value = getValue(10)
Long param2Value = getValue(20)

controller.request.content = '{"param1":<param1Value>,"param2":<param2Value>}'
controller.methodUnderTest()
def response = controller.response.json
}
```

In this how can i specify param1value and param2value for param1 and param2 parameters respectively. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonBuilder` as below.

```
void testMethod(){
    def controller = new DummyController()
    def reqJson = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

    reqJson {
        params1 getValue(10)
        params2 getValue(20)
    }

    controller.request.content = reqJson.toString()
    controller.methodUnderTest()
    def response = controller.response.json
}
```

or use `"""` or slashy string for the json string as:

```
controller.request.content = """{"param1":"$param1Value","param2":"$param2Value"}"""

controller.request.content = /{"param1":"$param1Value","param2":"$param2Value"}/
```

Comment: The foll way to put json object in a request is working:
controller.request.content = /{"param1":"$param1Value","param2":"$param2Value"}/
But i was trying to create a json object using JSONObject class. 
It is getting created properly but when json key/value pair are accessed in controller method, it is giving null.
Ex : 
    def exJSON = new JSONObject()
    exJSON.put("id",value1)
    exJSON.put("name",value2)
    controller.request.content = exJSON.toString()
    controller.methotToTest()

In controller method when "name" value is retrieved, it is coming as null

Comment: Did you check how does the json string look like? Try to debug/print `exJSON.toString()`.